# Auto created 7z files script, but need to strip old file extension from the output file name

Tags: 7-zip

In a script made by @Enteleform found here. (below)

---

```java
@Echo OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion



Rem //  7-Zip Executable Path
Set sevenZip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"



Rem // START: NewLine Variable Hack
Set newLine=^


Rem // END: NewLine Variable Hack !! DO NOT DELETE 2 EMPTY LINES ABOVE !!



Rem //  Set ErrorLog Variables
Set errorCount=0
Set separator=--------------------------------------------------------
Set errorLog=!newLine!!newLine!!separator!!newLine!!newLine!
Set errorPrefix=ERROR @:
Set successMessage=All Files Were Successfully Archived



Rem //  Loop Through Each Argument
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (%*) do (

    Rem //  Use Current Argument To set File, Folder, & Archive Paths
    SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set filePath="%%~x"
    Set directoryFiles="%%~x\*"
    Set archivePath="%%~x.zip"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    Rem //  Source Is A Folder
    if exist !directoryFiles! (
            Set sourcePath=!directoryFiles!
    )

    Rem //  Source Is A File
    if not exist !directoryFiles! (
            Set sourcePath=!filePath!
    )

    Rem //  Print Separator To Divide 7-Zip Output
    echo !newLine!!newLine!!separator!!newLine!!newLine!

    Rem //  Add Files To Zip Archive
    !sevenZip! A -TZIP !archivePath! !sourcePath!

    Rem //  Log Errors
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        Set /A errorCount=errorCount+1
        Set errorLog=!errorLog!!newLine!!errorPrefix!!sourcePath!
    )
)



Rem //  Print ErrorLog
if !errorCount!==0 (
    Set errorLog=!errorLog!!newLine!!successMessage!
)
Echo !errorLog!!newLine!!newLine!!newLine!



Rem //  Keep Window Open To View ErrorLog
pause
```

---

it works great however the script includes the original file extension in the naming of the created 7z file. (eg. "Picture1.jpg.7z") How can I strip the original file extension from the name of the newly created 7z file? (eg. "Picture1.7z")

Comment: I figured it out. line: Set archivePath="%%~x.zip" it should be "%%~nx.zip" the %~nx strips the extension only using the file name.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I strip the original file extension from the name of the newly created 7z file?

Use the `%~n1` [parameter extension](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Replace:

```
set archivePath="%%~x.zip"
```

With:

```
set archivePath="%%~nx.zip"
```

> **Parameter Extensions**
>
> ...
>
> `%~n1` Expand `%1` to a file Name without file extension `C:\utils\MyFile` or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash) - the last folder in that path.

Source - [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.